# Perl - Read multiple files and read line by line of the text file

Tags: perl

I am trying to read multiple .txt files in a folder. Each file should be read line by line, however, I failed to read multiple .txt files by using glob. Any advice on my code?

```
my %data;
@FILES = glob("*.txt");

$EmailMsg .= "EG. Folder(week) = Folder(CW01) --CW01 = Week 1 -- Number is week\n ";
$EmailMsg .= "=======================================================================================================\n";

# Try to Loop multiple files here
foreach my $file (@FILES) {
  local $/ = undef;
  open my $fh, '<', $file;
  $data{$file} = <$fh>;

  # Read the file one line at a time.
  while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/^\s+//;
    $line =~ s/\s+$//;
    my ($name, $date, $week) = split /\:/, $line;

    if ($name eq "NoneFolder") {
      $EmailMsg .= "Folder ($week) - No Folder created on the FTP! Failed to open folder!\n";
    }

    if ($name eq "EmptyFiles") {
      $EmailMsg .= "Folder ($week) - No Files insides the folder! Failed download files!\n";
    }

  }
}
$EmailMsg .= "=======================================================================================================\n";
$EmailMsg .= "Please note that if you receive this email means that the script is running fine just that no folder is created or no files inside the folder for the week on the FTP.\n";

# close the file.
#close <$fh>;
```

Currently output:

```
    EG. Folder(week) = Folder(CW01) --CW01 = Week 1 -- Number is week
  =======================================================================================================
    =======================================================================================================
    Please note that if you receive this email means that the script is running fine just that no folder is created or no files inside the folder for the week on the FTP.
```

It failed to get any .txt files.

Comment: Do you have [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) at the top of your script?  Along with [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) of course.

Comment: @Miller No Sir.. What is autodie use for?

Comment: You're attempting to open a file with `open my $fh, '<', $file;` without checking to see if it actually succeeds.  Good on you for using a lexical file handle, but unless you have `use autodie;` at the top of your script, you won't be alerted to any obvious errors, like missing path information for a file that you're trying to open.

Comment: @Miller oh.. after added `use autodie;` it still get the same output.

Comment: You should also `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of every Perl program you write, and declare variables as close as possible to their first point of use with `my`.

Comment: @Borodin i did use use warnings but not using `use strict` due to some of my variable get error on Global Symbol `variable` requires explicit package name.

Comment: You should *fix the problem* that `use strict` reveals. Working without it just hides any problems that you may have instead of correcting them. It is a lifeline and throwing it away is foolish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to read each file twice: firstly into the hash `%data` and then again line by line.

Once you have reached end of file, you have to either reopen the file or use `seek` to move the read pointer back to the beginning.

You also need to set `$/` back to its original value, otherwise your loop will read the entire file instead of one line at a time.

It's not clear whether you really need the second copy of the file data in the hash, but you can avoid having to reset `$/` by putting the change within a block, like this

```
open my $fh, '<', $file;
$data{$file} = do {
  local $/ = undef;
  <$fh>;
};
```

and then reset the file pointer to the start again before the `while` loop.

```
seek $fh, 0, 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
my @files=('Read a file.pl','Read a single text file.pl','Read only one 
file.pl','Read the file using while.pl','Reading the file.pl');
foreach my $i(@files) {
open(FH, "<$i");
{
    while (my $row = <FH>) {
        chomp $row;
        print "$row\n";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file globbing works for me.  You might want to specify scope for your @FILES variable and check that there actually are files matching the path you have specified,

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

## glob on all files in home directory
## see: http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html
use File::Glob ':globally';
my @configs = <~myname/project/etc/*.cfg>;

foreach my $fn (@configs) {
    print "file $fn\n";
}
```

your code,

```
my %data;
#here are some .c files,
my @FILES = glob("../*.c");
foreach my $fn (@FILES) {
    print "file $fn\n";
}

exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This way catches more garbage for about the same amount of code.

```
my $PATH = shift @ARGV ; 
chomp $PATH ; 

opendir(TXTFILE,$PATH) || die ("failed to opendir: $PATH") ; 
my @file = readdir TXTFILE ; 
closedir(TXTFILE) ; 

foreach(@file) { # 
   next unless ($_ =~ /\.txt$/i) ; # Only get .txt files
   $PATH =~ s/\/$//g ; $PATH =~ s/$/\// ; # Uniform trailing slash
   my $thisfile = $PATH . $_ ; # now a fully qualified filename 

   unless (open(THISFILE,$thisfile)) { # Notify on busted files.
      warn ("$thisfile failed to open") ;
      next ; 
   }

   while(<THISFILE>) { 
       # etc. etc. 
   }

   close(THISFILE) ; 
 }
```